# Searching a Nested multimap for values in C++?

Tags: c++, nested, multimap

I am trying to search a nested MultiMap in which the outer Multimap has a string key value and the value for each key is another multimap which has strings as key value pairs within it shown like this:

```
 multimap<string,map<string, string>> myMultMap;
myMultMap.insert(make_pair("distinct", makeMap("noun", "This is the first definition")));
myMultMap.insert(make_pair("distinct", makeMap("verb", "This is the second definition")));
myMultMap.insert(make_pair("distinct", makeMap("adjective", "This is the third definition")));
myMultMap.insert(make_pair("book", makeMap("noun", "This is the book noun definition")));
myMultMap.insert(make_pair("book", makeMap("verb", "This is the book verb definition")));
myMultMap.insert(make_pair("other", makeMap("noun", "This is the other noun definition")));
myMultMap.insert(make_pair("dumb", makeMap("noun", "This is the dumb noun definition")));
```

I am trying to make it an interactive, searchable map/dictionary such that if i enter "book" it outputs the keyword "book" and the verb definition and noun definition:

### Output:

***book [noun]: This is the book noun definition***

***book [verb]: This is the book verb definition***

so far i have tried using iterators and the .equals_range() method in the multimap class, and it works if i use "*noun*" as my second search parameter but if i search for *verb* nothing shows up.

```
pair <multimap<string, string>::iterator, multimap<string, string>::iterator> ret;

auto iter = myMultMap.find(str)->second;
ret = iter.equal_range("noun");


for (multimap<string,string>::iterator it=ret.first; it!=ret.second; ++it) {
    std::cout << str << " =>";
    std::cout << ' ' << it->second;
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

### edit

I forgot to add that the outer multimap also has multiple definitions per each Part of speech key.
`myMultMap.insert(make_pair("book", makeMap("noun", "This is the 1 definition")));
    myMultMap.insert(make_pair("book", makeMap("verb", "This is the book verb def1")));
    myMultMap.insert(make_pair("book", makeMap("verb", "This is the book verb def 2")));
    myMultMap.insert(make_pair("book", makeMap("verb", "This is the book def 1")));
    myMultMap.insert(make_pair("book", makeMap("noun", "This is the book noun def 2")));`

Comment: It's the outer map that has multiple values per key, not the inner one. You need to call `myMultMap.equal_range(str)` instead of `find`

Comment: Also you should check if your found iterator is dereferencable before using it.

Comment: I forgot to add that there are multiple definitions per key inside as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these complex data structures you just have to carefully think your way through what type each element returns and how to further reference that type. It's a mental challenge to begin with but it gets easier with practice.

I think maybe something like this is what you are after:

```
void output(std::multimap<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> mm, 
    std::string const& item)
{
    auto range = mm.equal_range(item);

    for(auto item_iter = range.first; item_iter != range.second; ++item_iter)
        for(auto const& entry: item_iter->second)
            std::cout << item_iter->first << " [" << entry.first << "]: " << entry.second << '\n';
}
```

The outer layer is a `std::multimap` which can have duplicate keys so `equal_range` is the usual way to search a given key.

That gives you a list of *iterators* so you loop through those. Each one dereferences to a `std::pair<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>`.

The `std::map` can then be iterated through using a range based for loop as shown.